# SEO best practices for one page websites?

Tags: seo, ranking, ajax, google-ranking, homepage

I build many one page websites that dynamically load content through AJAX/jQuery. I keep reading how bad one pagers are for SEO. Regardless, how can you get the most SEO results out of a one page website, without splitting it up into multiple pages?

Comment: Also many other questions and answers regarding SEO and Ajax of loading content: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=ajax%20content%20is%3aquestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google already tells you](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/?csw=1) what to do and how to handle this. Specifically it's for ajax'd web sites.